# Printing validation message on the same page in PHP

Tags: php

Hi I have this function in handling upload errors.

```
function error($error, $location, $seconds = 5)
{
    header("Refresh: $seconds; URL=\"$location\"");
    echo 'Error :' . $error . ' Please correct before proceeding.';
    exit;
}
```

Since this is `echo`'s the message, you know the message shows not in the same page and you need to hit browser back to return to the original content page.

What I wanted is the validation messages to be shown on the same page, so I tried changing the code to following.

```
function error($error)
{
    $ErrMsg = 'Error :' . $error . ' Please correct before proceeding.';

}
```

And later in the form in a table I have something like following to call the massage.

```
<td><?php if(!empty($ErrMsg)) echo $ErrMsg; ?></td>
```

However this method doesn't seems to be giving me the solution I need, which is to print the validation message on the same page.

Can anyone help?

thanks.

Comment: `$ErrMsg` was declared inside a function and won't be available anywhere beyond that scope

Comment: Does your form submit to itself or does it submit somewhere else?

Comment: @Geo Oh that's new learning for me. So what would you suggest in such a scenario?

Comment: @user1477388 yes the this has a PHP SELF

Comment: @konaramudi Read more about `varaible scope`: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: Thanks @AlexP will read that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use ajax to call the error function and output the message on the page.

Or you could set a $_POST, $_GET, or $_SESSION variable to pass the error message onto the next page.

**Session example:**

```
function error($error)
{
    $_SESSION['ErrMsg'] = 'Error :' . $error . ' Please correct before proceeding.';
}
```

And later...

```
<td>
<?php if (!empty($_SESSION['ErrMsg'])) {
 echo $_SESSION['ErrMsg']; 
}?>
</td>
```

**If the form posts to the same page it's on, you could try something like this:**

```
function uploadValidation()
{
    $errorReason = '';
    // do validation here
    // if something goes wrong $errorReason = 'reason for error'

    if (!empty($errorReason)) {
        return 'Error :' . $errorReason . ' Please correct before proceeding.';
    } else {
        // success stuff
        // maybe return thanks message or redirect somewhere else?
        return 'You upload real good!';
    }
}

$validationMessage = uploadValidation();
?>

And later in the form in a table I have something like following to call the massage.

<td><?= $validationMessage ?></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `{` after your `if...` codes and just before `echo` and a closing `}` after your `echo...` codes.

Comment: If you were to post the suggested code in full, rather than explain the changes, it would be much clearer what you mean.

Comment: @AlexP `<td><?php if(!empty($ErrMsg)) {echo $ErrMsg; } ?></td>` Use this and try.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually pretty hard to tell what you are trying to achieve based on your description. But try this:

```
<?php

function error($error) {
    return 'Error :' . $error . ' Please correct before proceeding.';
}

?>
```

And then:

```
<td><?php echo error('YOUR ERROR CODE') ?></td>
```